# How can I trasfer a big site to another server?

Tags: linux, ftp, plesk

i need to change server for a site of 250gb.
 I can't do any backup even on external server because there isn't enough space to do that. 
Plesk migrator not work I try to download by ftp but it's very slow and not download all files

how can i move?

Comment: Why not restore the site on the other server from your backups?

Comment: If you have shell access to either server, use it. // Also, getting some storage is cheap. Consider implementing *automated* backups with that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have no backups, so you need to transfer the files off the original server. Remember this may include "*hidden*" things like databases, configuration files as well as the expected content files.

The only options to make this faster are:

1. Use compression... if the data can get a good compression ratio
2. Get physical access to the server - you visit it, or it visits you
3. Get remote hands to physically attach a hard disk that can subsequently be shipped to you ([sneakernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet)).

In your quest, you might like to use a tool like [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), which can be used to restart a transfer that is interrupted.

Comment: there isn't enough space. I pay a sys admin and he move all with rsync!